# Is it possible to use a SOCKS5 proxy for the macOS terminal on a local machine?

Tags: macos, proxy, socks-proxy

Many websites, for example: [getgrav.org](https://getgrav.org) is blocked by my ISP, so I even can’t  download it via composer in my terminal.

Is there a way to use SOCKS5 proxy in the macOS terminal? A VPN is not solution, because it will make all my traffic to go through it.

Is it possible to use a SOCKS5 proxy for the macOS terminal on a local machine?

Comment: It depends on the particular program you're using; some have command-line options (e.g. `curl --socks5 host[:port]`), some look for environment variables (e.g. `export http_proxy=socks5://host[:port]`), some have both options, and some don't support socks at all. You need to check the documentation for the specific program(s) you're using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just found a nice app called Proxifier, it worked the way I needed.

It allows to proxify requests for certain processes, e.g.: Chrome, Safari, Messengers, etc.

Comment: Happy you solved your issue, but this is not really an answer at all.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.